# Emacs ECB cursor invisible in directory tree

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

I've installed Emacs on OSX Snow Leopard using Homebrew (brew install emacs --cocoa).  Having brought over my .emacs.d from Ubuntu, everything seems ok except when browsing the directory tree the cursor is hidden, so I can't see which directory is highlighted.

I've tried removing everything non-essential from init.el, but no change.  Is this a quirk of my Homebrew install?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a true answer, but I would suggest you use the Cocoa Emacs.app [get a build here](http://emacsformacosx.com/).

Comment: Just tried it, same problem.  I think it's something to do with the icons used in OSX.  Switching to ASCII representation works ok, just a bit clunky.

Comment: You can (probably!) customise ECB to use another cursor.